# QGIS problem with unavailable layers when opening a project

Tags: qgis

I have a .qgz project file that I'm sharing with a colleague, the layers are mostly shapefiles stored on our local network server.  I can open and work with the project with no problems at all, but when she opens the project, she gets the "Handle unavailable layers" window with "Localized" Datasource files...  We're using absolute paths in the project, and she can browse to the files (or open the project and change datasource), but what does "localized" mean and why is it only happen to her, and not when I open the project?

We're both using 3.16.

[image: Handle Unavailable Layers]

Comment: Have you verified where the faulty layers are saved? Is the project also stored on the server?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably set in your QGIS general configuration localized paths ("Settings" menu > "Options" > "Data Sources" tab) and your colleague does not have the config you set on your own machine. Info mentioned in last point of section of the official doc [Data Sources Settings](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#data-sources-settings)

On your machine, you should see a non empty block in red part from my screen capture

[image: Localized Data paths configuration section]

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you, that's exactly what it was - I had no idea.